# How do I fix this Idle-Car Game Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to have a game, in which everyone can buy cars (and I save that data to playerprefs). So I have 9 trails for the cars in my game and I am trying to write some code so that when you press a button the car & the trail for that car will show up.

When the button next to it is clicked, it saves that data so when people restart the game, they will still have the car & trail open and won't need to press the button again.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public Button[] TrailLevel; 
    public GameObject[] Cars, Trails;
    public Text text; 
    public int CurrentCarToSpawn = 0; 

    private void Start()
    { }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        UpdateCar();
    }

    public void InstantiateCar()
    {
        TrailLevel[CurrentCarToSpawn].gameObject.active = false;
        MineLevel[CurrentCarToSpawn+1].interactable = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TrailCountA", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TrailCountA") + 1);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        CurrentCarToSpawn++;
        UpdateCar();
    }

    void UpdateCar()
    {
        int TrailCountA= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TrailCountA", 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < TrailLevel.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 > TrailCountA)
            {
                 TrailLevel.interactable = false;
            }
            if (TrailLevel.interactable)
            {
                Trains[CurrentCarToSpawn].gameObject.active = true;
                Mines[CurrentCarToSpawn].gameObject.active = true;
            }
        }
        text.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TrailCountA").ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggested an edit to improve the code formatting. One line in your UpdateCar()-function looked odd. So i changed **(TrailLevel.interactable)** to **if (TrailLevel.interactable)**. Please undo the change if it does not match with your source code.

Comment: It's just copy-paste mistake, it's fine in unity,

Comment: I agree with @Hyarus fix the formating of your code, it will be much easier to get an answer if you do that.

Comment: @Eddge I fixed it, please help me to figure it out tho :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see with your code, this is how I would approach it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public Button[] TrailLevel; 
    public GameObject[] Cars, Trails;
    public Text text; 
    public int CurrentCarToSpawn = 0; 

    private void Start()
    { 
        // Load the current car. ADDED
        CurrentCarToSpawn  = PlayerPrefs.getInt("savedSelection", 0);
        // Since we are loading the last selection, we need to call our
        // instantiation method so it can activate the appropriate 
        // GameObjects.
        InstantiateCar();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        UpdateCar();
    }

    public void InstantiateCar()
    {
        TrailLevel[CurrentCarToSpawn].gameObject.active = false;
        MineLevel[CurrentCarToSpawn+1].interactable = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TrailCountA", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TrailCountA") + 1);
        // Save that this is our current selection.
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("savedSelection", CurrentCarToSpawn);             
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        CurrentCarToSpawn++;
        UpdateCar();
    }

    void UpdateCar()
    {
        int TrailCountA= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TrailCountA", 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < TrailLevel.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 > TrailCountA)
            {
                 TrailLevel.interactable = false;
            }
            if (TrailLevel.interactable)
            {
                Trains[CurrentCarToSpawn].gameObject.active = true;
                Mines[CurrentCarToSpawn].gameObject.active = true;
            }
        }
        text.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TrailCountA").ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I input this code, doesn't work the buttons are all interactable, and when you press them they do nothing at all. please help! :)

Comment: If they are all interactable then its because you didn't deactivate them, and if they do nothing when you click them its because you didnt give them an action on click.